# Section numbering does not comply. I am using Lyx, Document class 'Report (standard class)'. Please help

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, lyx

I am writing my thesis in Lyx, using Document class 'Report (Standard Class)'.
I have one main document 'thesis.lyx', in which I include all my chapters as Child Documents.

In the main document 'thesis.lyx' I set these settings:

[image: Main Document settings]

However when I export the document as PDF (LuaTeX), anything beyond 'Subsection' is not numbered within my thesis.

Here is a minimal LyX example: [Ella_J_minimal_Lyx](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9hzj4uybnj8zlbt/Lyx_Ella_J.zip?dl=0)

How can I solve this?

Many thanks,
Ella

Comment: This is probably nothing about Lyx. You want to change the "numbering depth" of the document. I dont know if you can change the source code within lyx, but you need to add \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}, see http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-secnumdep.html

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal LyX example? For more information see http://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: @Bort your suggestion doesn't work as it is related to how Chapters are numbered - not related to subsections.

Comment: @scottkosty I have done so (https://www.dropbox.com/s/9hzj4uybnj8zlbt/Lyx_Ella_J.zip?dl=0) thanks for the suggestion. Hopefully now it is easier to see what I mean, because although I have added Chapter, section, subsection, and subsubsection , the later isn't numbered within my document.

Comment: @EllaJay Thank you for your attempt. However, this is not a minimal example. It seems actually quite complicated to me, with ERT all over the place and a complicated LaTeX preamble. The link I gave above discusses how to create a minimal example, and why it is important.

Comment: @scottkosty apologies, this was my first attempt at a minimal lyx, and I see your point. I tried to delete all unecesary contents, lyx files, and as much ERT but I didn't think about the preamble. Thanks for your feedback and next time I will do my best to do a better job - so that you (all) can be helped in heping me - much appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More of a comment, but I wanted to include the picture:

Have you at least tried my suggestion? (I really cant tell if thats your problem, but it sounds like it), consider the following near to minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\section{section}
\subsection{subsection}
\subsubsection{subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

which merely creates some structure elements and fumbles around the secnumdepth, for the one of it I used article so as to show that is not chapter-related (I think you misread the resource I linked to)

[image: secnumdepth example]

My understanding is that you want to achieve the last behaviour (and yes the numbering scheme in the table of contents would be the same)

Edit: Obviously I can neither count nor look, the fourth iteration is superfluous

Comment: Bort - this works! I can't thank you enough - and kudos for being persistant. I was trying this in the main 'parent' lyx file which didn't work as I wanted it to. When I add it at the begining of each 'child' lyx document then I get the exact result I want. Again thank you!